# All combinations of all possible lengths in Julia

Tags: list-comprehension, julia

For instance, given the input `n = 3` I want to obtain:

```
[(1,),(2,),(3,),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,2,3)]
```

I tried a python-like syntax:

```
combs = [comb for x in collect(1:n) for comb in combinations(collect(1:n),x)]
```

but I got the following error message:

```
ERROR: LoadError: syntax: expected ]
```

I've also tried this:

```
combs = [comb for comb in vcat([combinations(collect(1:n),x) for x in collect(1:n)])]
```

but I got:

```
[Base.Combinations{Array{Int64,1}}([1,2,3],1),Base.Combinations{Array{Int64,1}}([1,2,3],2),Base.Combinations{Array{Int64,1}}([1,2,3],3)]
```

How to get the result I want?

Comment: `combs = vcat([[comb for comb in combinations(1:n,x)] for x=1:n]...)` is closest to the first attempt which works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is

```
n = 3
vcat([collect(combinations(1:n,i)) for i=1:n]...)
```

OK?

Output:

```
7-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1]    
 [2]    
 [3]    
 [1,2]  
 [1,3]  
 [2,3]  
 [1,2,3]
```

OTHER METHODS:

Another method is `[65-findin(bits(i),'1') for i=1:(2^n-1)]`, which points the way to a very efficient implementation along the lines of:

```
tmp = BitVector(sizeof(Int)*8)
[begin tmp.chunks[1]=i; find(tmp) end for i=1:(2^n-1)]
```

although it uses BitVector internals, which might be obscure.

For memory efficiency:

```
using Iterators
chain(([combinations(1:n,i) for i=1:n])...) |> collect
```

(could be used directly as iterator in a `for` loop). But with `Iterators` one could use:

```
drop(subsets(1:n),1) |> collect
```

which is readable.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks (I'll use the first method)! But I would like to understand: 1. why did I get `expected ]` error in my first example? 2. why is it not possible to make a list-comprehension of the form: `[x for y in z for x in y]`. Is it because Julia only accepts one `for` inside list comprehensions or is it because it wasn't writtent well? I mean, that seems the most logical way to write it.

Comment: Yes, comprehensions have one `for` inside. But the second version you wrote was almost correct. Using another `for` in a nested comprehension is OK. You should note `combinations` returns an iterator, so a `collect` should be done before a `vcat`.

Comment: @Pigna you can't have two `for`s inside the same comprehension, but you can have more that one variable in play, ie. n-dimensional comprehensions, one for each dimension, for example: `[i+j+k for i = 1:3, j = 1:3, k = 1:3]` returns a __*3x3x3*__ 3-dimensional `Array{Int64,3}`.